# How to refresh full page periodically

Tags: jsf

I am trying to automatically refesh an page in JSF, but I cannot seem to find any clear example. can I use PrimeFaces to refresh the whole page say every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Primefaces Poll](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) to do this:

```
<p:poll interval="10"   
        listener="#{counterBean.listener}" update="@all" />
```

This scripts calls every 10 seconds CounterBean.listener() and refreshes the whole page.

Comment: should I replace the conterbean with my managed bean or use the counterbean itself? when I use my bean it only increments once

Comment: the "CountBean" is just a placeHolder from the primefaces documentation that should be replaced with your managed bean name.

Comment: so I created the same counterbean in the example and used the poll code above and when I edit a value in a row in my table (JPA) it is updated in the jsf data table after 10 sec. However this is not the same if I say add a new record to a table or delete a record(primefaces data table not updated). so half of the quesiton answered. But  i will mark it for now..

Comment: Finally the whole form was updated when i used form in place of update= @all. THanks